# How to convert ppt to HTML in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website, admin can upload a PPT & on submission, I am  in need to convert to html.

I was using `OpenXML` library for the Word document. I thought the same lib can be used for PPT also. But not finding the method for the same.

```
namespace OpenXML_Sample
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExportHTML.GenerateHTML(@"D:\test.pptx");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ExportHTML
{
    public static XElement GenerateHTML(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (PresentationDocument pptDoc=
                    PresentationDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
                {
                    HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
                    {
                        PageTitle = "My Page Title"
                    };
                   //not accepting pptDoc as parameter,throws compile time error.
                    XElement xHtml = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(pptDoc, settings);
                    var html = xHtml.ToString();
                    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\sample.html", html,Encoding.UTF8);
                    return xHtml;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new FileLoadException(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
        }

    }


}
```

}

How do I pass the ppt document to the method to generate the html document of the uploaded ppt file.

Would welcome for any other(free) api as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Aspose library before and I believe it supports what you are wanting to achieve.

A quick search on their forums revealed [this post](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/441044/converting-ppt-to-html.aspx) which might suit your needs;

Comment: Its a very useful library for my requirement. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries, it has some nuances in places but it's served me quite well and their forums are fairly well manned and happy to help.

Comment: Its not a free lib to use. Any free lib you know

Comment: Not really, the only other way you might have is using the Office Interop libraries but that requires Office to be installed on the machines that you'll be running this program on

Answer (score 0):

web,

I like to share that Aspose.Slides for .NET supports exporting presentation file to HTML and you don't even need to install MS Office for this on your machine. All you need to do is to use the appropriate functionality in API. Please visit this [documentation link](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Converting+Presentation+to+HTML) for your kind reference. If you still have an issue then please contact us in [Aspose.Slides support](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.slides-product-family/109/showforum.aspx) forum.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of converting in C# with iSpring Platform http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-platform. It isn’t tailored for a certain programming language, but it’s easy to use it with C#. First of all, there are some examples, and secondly, there’s a Code Builder app, so you can set the necessary conversion configuration and use the generated C# code in your app.